# Bash: Why does K get appended to the end of base64 encoded value when running via script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

If I encode via

```bash
$#:>    echo -ne "Apps:apps1" | openssl enc -base64
QXBwczphcHBzMQ==
```

but if i write a script for the same in temp.sh file.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
echo -ne "Apps:apps1" | openssl enc -base64
```

this gets printed.

`LW5lIEFwcHM6YXBwczEK`

and run

```bash
$#:> sh temp.sh
$#:> sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin22)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: "LW5lIEFwcHM6YXBwczEK" decodes to the string "-ne Apps:apps1<newline>". This happens because `echo` with options is hopelessly inconsistent between different versions and modes. If you value your sanity, don't use it, use `printf` with an appropriate format string: `printf '%s' "Apps:apps1" | openssl enc -base64`. See ["Why is printf better than echo?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Comment: From what I see, you are using bash `echo` on the command line and `sh` echo in your script.  What happens if you replace both `echo` by `command echo -ne "Apps:apps1" | openssl ....`?

Comment: Depending on Bash version it could be done as `openssl enc -base64 <<<"Apps:apps1"` also